# Extending Class with Many Parameters

Tags: kotlin

I have a class called A:

```
open class A (a: String, b: String, c: String)
```

And a class B which extends A:

```
class B(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String) : A(a, b, c)
```

My question is if there is a way to do something like this, to avoid declaring all the parameters of A within the B constructor:

```
class B(super, d:String) : A(super)
```

If not, there should be =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a common interface for the classes, and then use delegation to get quite close to what you want. Like this:

```
interface C {
  val a: String
  val b: String
  val c: String
}

class A(override val a: String,
        override val b: String,
        override val c: String) : C

class B(c: C, val d: String) : C by c
```

Doing this, you can instantiate a `B` like this:

```
val b = B(A("1", "2", "3"), "4")
```

Answer (score 4):

[No](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html), Kotlin does not contain any construct that allows you simplify constructor parameters that match the parameters of the superclass.

I don't think I agree that this should be a feature of the language, but I would recommend starting a conversation on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT) if you think it should be.

Answer (score 3):

When you meet this problem, you should ask yourself **why** such a class need many parameters/dependencies rather than find out the solution by language syntax. Maybe its responsibility is unclear.

**IF** there are many domain concepts mixed in a class, then you need to redesign your classes as below:

```
data class C(val a: String, val b: String, val c: String)

open class A(val c:C)

class B(c:C, val d: String) : A(c)
```

**IF** you found `B` not **is-A** `A`, then you must using composition rather than inheritance, for example:

```
open class A (a: String, b: String, c: String)

class B(val a:A, val d: String)
```

Comment: He, I was going to write up something like this. Now I cant ;-) But Glad to see that some folks get beyond the problem on the surface!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such a way. Unfortunately you need to do this manually